# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo in a New Project - Android 3 Canary 7

Tags: java, android

I have a problem, I have it with all my projects, so I came up with a new project with Android 3 Canary 7, but it always gives me the same error.

I have MacOS Sierra 10.12.6

It's a complete new project, so i don't know what to do to solve it

This error occurs:

> 07-24 10:25:57.776 29708-29708/com.estebanmoncaleano.myapplication
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.estebanmoncaleano.myapplication, PID: 29708
>                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>
> ComponentInfo{com.estebanmoncaleano.myapplication/com.estebanmoncaleano.myapplication.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.estebanmoncaleano.myapplication.MainActivity" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.estebanmoncaleano.myapplication-2/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.estebanmoncaleano.myapplication-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2972)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
>                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.estebanmoncaleano.myapplication.MainActivity" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.estebanmoncaleano.myapplication-2/base.apk", zip file
>   "/data/app/com.estebanmoncaleano.myapplication-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>                                                                                            at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1094)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2962)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3243) 
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:218) 
>                                                                                            at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718) 
>                                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6917) 
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
>                                                                                         Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.estebanmoncaleano.myapplication.MainActivity
>                                                                                            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                                                                 ... 13 more
>                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the
>   boot class loader; no stack available

My Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.estebanmoncaleano.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.estebanmoncaleano.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Gradle Proyect Settings:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
android.enableAapt2=false
```

What do you think I can do to solve my problem?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please show us your `activity_main.xml` and `MainActivity.java`

Answer (score 0):

Clean your project, rebuild and run it. That's working for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems instant run is broken.
Try `Stop` → `Run`(not `Apply changes` - yellow lighting-shape), or `Clean` → `Rebuild`.